# Как поменять язык на странице через консоль?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите какой скрипт нужно вести в console, чтобы поменять язык на странице https://my.ecwid.com/cp/?

Answer (score 1):

На данной форме входа язык определяется значением куки lang. Так что нужно изменить значение куки и обновить страницу. Например для включения русского языка выполните код:

```
document.cookie = 'lang=ru;path=/';
location.reload();
```

А для английского языка вот такой код:

```
document.cookie = 'lang=us;path=/';
location.reload();
```